# Swift - Reload UIPageViewController with new information in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, reload, uipageviewcontroller, viewdidappear

How to reload UIPageViewController in `viewDidAppear`?

There, I refresh information from CoreData and I want to updated values when the view appears.

I tried with function `reloadInputViews()`, but unsuccessfully only when you start to open pages then the information is updated.

Comment: is your "`UIPageViewController`" an "`IBOutlet`" in your view controller?  Is your "`UIPageViewController`" subclassed?

Comment: You need to use the `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` function to load the view controllers for the page(s) you want to reload.

Comment: mind helping me out, i have a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764415/reload-uipageviewcontroller-json-swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to reload the ViewControllers inside the UIPageViewController, just re-set them with:

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

if you are going to update your viewControllers from inside a viewController, you have to call it this way:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let viewControllers: [UIViewControllers] = [UIViewController()]
    if let pageViewController = parentViewController as? UIPageViewController {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
self.setViewControllers(pageViewController, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: {})
}`
prints an 
error `ViewController does not have a member named setViewControllers`

Comment: this `if` never executes

Comment: Mind helping me out here, I have a similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764415/reload-uipageviewcontroller-json-swift